# how to escape pipe symbol | in bat scripts?

Tags: pipe, echo, batch-file

I need to echo commad usage like this in batch script named command.bat

```
command.bat on|off
```

I cant use

```
echo %0 on|off
```

I know I  can use

```
echo "%0 on|off"
```

but it puts quotes along

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use a caret.

eg.

```
echo %0 on^|off
```