# Set arbitrary text to windows clipboard

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, clipboard, echo, escaping

I'm using `clip` to set text on the clipboard.
To do that, I use `echo`.

```
echo Works|clip
```

The problem is when the text contains special characters, eg. `|` `"`.

```
echo (TRUE|FALSE)|clip
echo " is a Quote Mark|clip
```

How should the text for `echo` be escaped?
Is there a better way to set text to the clipboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to escape pipe symbol | in bat scripts?](https://superuser.com/questions/270004/how-to-escape-pipe-symbol-in-bat-scripts)

Comment: @phuclv Not really. It's a bit more complicated. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How should the text for echo be escaped?

Use the `^` escape character.

When piping to clip, the `^` needs escaping as well.

Example 1:

```
> echo (TRUE^^^|FALSE)|clip
```

Contents of clipboard:

```
(TRUE|FALSE)
```

Example 2:

```
> echo ^" is a Quote Mark|clip
```

Contents of clipboard:

```
" is a Quote Mark
```

> **Escape Character**
>
> `^`  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text.
>
> When piping or redirecting any of these characters you should prefix
>   with the escape character: `& \ < > ^ |`
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> ^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^
> ```

Source  [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)

Comment: The problem with the `"` character, is that when present, the text is not piped to the clip command. The `|clip` is echo'd with the preceding text. The escaped pipe causes an error when piping to clip.

Comment: `"` needs escaping when piping to clip. Also need to escape `^` when piping to clip. Answer updated.